# C++ / SDL: vector / surface issues

Tags: c++, sdl, access-violation

Here is the newest problem I am running into. I have a class called Projectiles which holds the basic makeup of a projectile. It's coordinates, and the image which it uses. Here is the basic structure:

```
class Projectile
{
    private:
        void load();

    public:
        SDL_Surface *surface;
        SDL_Surface* returnSurface()
        {
            return surface;
        }

        Projectile( int );
        void coordinates( int, int );

        int type;
        int width, height;

        int positionX, positionY;

        bool alive;
};

Projectile::Projectile( int type )
{
    type = 1;
    alive = true;
    width  = 83;
    height = 46;
}

void Projectile::load()
{
    SDL_Surface* loadedImage = NULL;

    loadedImage = IMG_Load( "hero.png" );
    surface = SDL_DisplayFormat( loadedImage );

    SDL_FreeSurface( loadedImage );
}

void Projectile::coordinates( int x, int y )
{
    positionX = x;
    positionY = y;
}
```

Now, I also have my hero class which holds the projectile objects in a vector like such:

> vector< Projectile > projectiles;

I have a method in the hero class which makes a new projectile and pushes it into this vector like so:

```
void Hero::newProjectile( int type )
{
    projectiles.push_back( Projectile( type ) );
    projectileCount++;
}
```

and then a draw method which is called at the very end of my main loop which does the following:

```
void Hero::drawProjectileState( SDL_Surface* destination )
{   
    for( int i = 0; i < projectileCount; i++ )
    {
        SDL_Rect offset;
        offset.x = positionX;
        offset.y = positionY;
        SDL_BlitSurface( projectiles[i].returnSurface(), NULL, destination, &offset );
    }
}
```

conceptually, I thought this would work just fine. Originally my projectile class held ALL of the projectiles coordinates in its own vector, but I came across a problem when I wanted to delete them. Since they all used the same surface resource, deleting one while another was on the screen would cause the game to crash. I thought this would solve the problem ( each having their own surface resource ), but I am getting

> Access violation reading location 0xccccccf8.

when it attempts to draw the projectile at :

`SDL_BlitSurface( projectiles[i].returnSurface(), NULL, destination, &offset );`

I have a feeling i am misunderstanding the way the surface referencing works. What would be the best way to give each projectile its own surface, so that I can delete them independently?

**edit:** just to clear up possible confusion, I want to be able to FREE the surfaces independently. Freeing a surface once one projectile dies, but another was still on the screen is what was causing the crashes initially.

Comment: Giving them each their own surface?  Why not use a `std::shared_ptr<surface>`, which automatically deletes a surface after it's not used anymore?  Or make one surface for the duration of the program and have them all use the one?

Comment: Also, why do you use `projectileCount` instead of `projectiles.size()`?

Comment: That gives me a signed/unsigned mismatch.

Comment: @Mooing Duck the problem I had when they all shared the same surface, was that every time a projectile was shot, it was still allocated in the memory. It took 12kb I believe per shot, so after some time, it took up a good amount of memory. However, i was not aware of the shared surface. Will this avoid the issue?

Comment: `(int)projectiles.size()` avoids the mismatch.  (Besides, that's just a warning.  As long as you have less than ~2 billion you'll be fine.)
If the surface is shared, it shouldn't take more memory.

Comment: **DO NOT** put an SDL_Surface pointer in a shared_ptr.  shared_ptr will call `delete` on the pointer, and you don't do that with SDL_Surface pointers.  You call SDL_FreeSurface.

Comment: Might I suggest that having a type field in your class is something that a little inheritance magic should be covering instead.  Saves the switch(type) stuff you'll need to do later on as well.

Comment: @Michael Dorgan That is a great suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Projectile::Projectile( int type )
{
    type = 1;
    alive = true;
    width  = 83;
    height = 46;
}

void Hero::newProjectile( int type )
{
    projectiles.push_back( Projectile( type ) );
    projectileCount++;
}
```

In the code above, you never loaded a surface.  You never even initialized `surface`, so it's pointing off in space, hence the access violation in `drawProjectileState` when you do this:

```
SDL_BlitSurface( projectiles[i].returnSurface(), NULL, destination, &offset );
```

Comment: The surface is loaded and stored in the Projectile class.

Comment: @Headspin: Where?  Show the code where that is done.  You showed the `load` function, but I don't see you calling it anywhere.

Comment: I was under the impression it was loaded inside the projectile class and the returned with `projectiles[i].returnSurface()` Sorry I am still new to all of this

Comment: A way to help prevent this type of error is to always initialize _all_ variables in the constructor/initializer list, even if they're NULL.

Comment: Wont this defeat the purpose of wanting each projectile to have it's own surface resource, so I can free them independently?

Comment: @Headspin: (re your second comment) Nope, all you do there is return the (un-initialized) SDL_Surface pointer.  (re your third comment) I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: What do you mean it returns the (un-initialized) SDL_Surface pointer. I was under the impression `surface = SDL_DisplayFormat( loadedImage );` would 'initialize' it.

Comment: @Headspin: That line of code is in the `load` function.  Nowhere in the code you showed us is the `load` function called.

Comment: This is the part where facepalm. Wow, its been a long Thursday at the office. Thanks mate!

Comment: I've got to say though. Even after I free the surface, and delete the vector, my memory continues to go up with every shot, and does not get free'd up at all once the projectiles are removed.

Comment: @Headspin: Make another post with a question about this problem.  Be sure to include the relevant code, such as the part where your surfaces are being freed.